# Android see if application is disabled

Tags: android, android-intent

In our app we have intent to start Skype. The method looks like this:

```
public void startSkype(View view) {
    if (!isSkypeClientInstalled()) {
        openMarket();
        return;
    }
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("skype:" + getString(R.string.usr_name) + "?chat"));
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It works fine in most cases, but to day we received a crash

```
Caused by android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.skype.raider/com.skype.raider.Main};
```

After trying to reproduce it for a while we found that it happens if application is set to `Disabled` in phone settings (not all phones have this setting). So is there a way to see if application is not available or do I have to wrap the method in ugly `try-catch` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the field `enabled` of `ApplicationInfo`:

> public boolean enabled
>   When false, indicates that all components
>   within this application are considered disabled, regardless of their
>   individually set enabled status.
>
> Reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#enabled

For example:

```
ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("package_name", 0);
boolean isAppEnabled = applicationInfo.enabled;
```